# Zero iAd requests for the lifetime of the app

Tags: ios, ipad, iad, ads

I have incorporated ads into an iOS 7 iPad application using iAd system. And I have successfully tested ad integration - could see test advertisement for iAd. But I have never seen live ads since the application release in the App Store - iAd portal always shows 0 requests though the app status is "Live Ads".

I have implemented both interstitial and banner ads (landscape mode) and got ads with message "You're connected to iAd" while testing on a device and the simulator. However, I do not see any ads in the app after it is live in the App Store.

1. I have implemented interstitial ads as following:

   ```
   // AppDelegate's application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
   [UIViewController prepareInterstitialAds];

   // Controller's viewDidLoad:
   self.interstitialPresentationPolicy = ADInterstitialPresentationPolicyManual;

   // When a user transitions from one screen to another within an application:
   [self requestInterstitialAdPresentation];
   ```
2. Banner ads as following:

   ```
   // ViewController's viewDidLoad:
   _bannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithAdType:ADAdTypeBanner];
   _bannerView.delegate = self;
   [self.view addSubview:_bannerView];

   -(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
       CGRect contentFrame = self.view.bounds, bannerFrame = CGRectZero;
       bannerFrame.size = [_bannerView sizeThatFits:contentFrame.size];

       if (_bannerView.bannerLoaded) {
           bannerFrame.origin.y = 0.0;
       } else {
           bannerFrame.origin.y = -bannerFrame.size.height;
       }
       _bannerView.frame = bannerFrame;
   }
   ```

I requested technical support from the DTS team, but they were unable to provide me any support on the issue and offered to contact the iAd Network Support Team which I had already done twice. They forwarded my request to an "appropriate team" a month ago and no reply since then. After following up the inquiry, they say that the iAd App Network team is still reviewing my request.

Any ideas how to resolve my issue, how to move on? Can it be an issue with my code?

Comment: Have you enabled iAds for your app in iTunesconnect?

Comment: Yes, I did, otherwise, I guess I wouldn't see test ads and not get the app showed up in iAd Network with Live Ads status. Though now there is no longer need to enable each app for iAd in the Manage Your Apps module (after iAd App Network Configuration Update).

Comment: Did you complete all of the Agreements, Tax and Banking forms?

Comment: One more thing to check - did you check "Used by kids"(or how it's called in iTunes Connect) for that app? If yes - that may be the case as such ads are very rare.

Answer (score 0):

I have an iPhone only application that only gets ads on the iPhone and on the iPad it does not get any ads. So I don't think you have an issue with actual code, also since you get the test ads in the simulator.

I would suggest you look at: [iAd not working on iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10243188/iad-not-working-on-ipad) and [iAd works in iPhone but not iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487856/iad-works-in-iphone-but-not-ipad).

Answer (score -1):

Where are you live? Are you sure, what [service iAd support](https://iadworkbench.apple.com/app/?page=routing#routing) your region and location for target advertisement?

> *iAd campaigns currently run in Australia, Canada, France, Germany, Hong Kong, Ireland, Italy, Japan, Mexico, New Zealand, Russia, Spain, Switzerland, Taiwan, the United Kingdom and the United States

Also may be the situation, iAd don't have target asd for your location at the moment...

P.S. I'm from Russia and I saw iAd's banner only once...

Comment: What does my location have to do with iAd requests statistics? I have uploads from the US, Europe etc, but iAd network shows that there are no iAd requests for my app at all (not only from my personal iPad!).

Comment: It's can mean, that iAd service don't have ads for currents devices... It happens... sometimes....

Comment: Sorry, but you've got mixed up... I am talking about 0 "requests" (Number of ads requested by the app)! And you are pointing to "Impression" - A single appearance of a banner ad on a page. It can be that there are no ads to fill a banner, but there should be requests for iAd ads sent by the app.